# NGINX - Remove index.php from the end of the URL

Tags: nginx, redirect, url

I can access my webpages with "www.dom.com/mypage" which will redirect to "www.dom.com/mypage/". "www.dom.com/mypage/index.php" is the main file but I want to remove this from the url so if you type this in it will redirect you to "www.dom.com/mypage/".

All links display the right page but i want to remove it from the URL.

Answer (score 1):

You need something like

```
location /index.php {
   rewrite ^/index\.php(.*)$ /mypage/$1 redirect;
}
```

You might want to look at [rewrites](http://nginx.org/en/docs/http/ngx_http_rewrite_module.html#rewrite) and [location](http://nginx.org/en/docs/http/ngx_http_core_module.html#location)

Comment: Yes, I have tried this, but it always redirects to the ROOT...

Comment: I am sorry, I have edited my answer

Comment: I would use `permanent` instead of `redirect`. `redirect` is a 302 redirect, which is practically never useful.

Comment: I didn't know what kind of redirect he wanted so I used the less permanent one. But you are right.